# How to make a context free grammar for a particular case

Tags: context-free-grammar

the problem is like this

Create a CFG that generates {a^i b^j: 2i < j + 2 < 3i}.
 my problem is that there way to many cases here. for example this does not work for j=1,2,4. also  for j=5,6,7,8,9 we need to have i=3,3,4,4,4. so how do i handle something like this, are there any tricks to doing stuff like this or am i making it harder then it looks.

Comment: This is not context-free. You have implied context.

Comment: >< guess my teacher made a mistake.

Comment: @apmasell: What context are you talking about? It's certainly context-free.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it harder than it is.

Coming up with grammars is a classic recursive analysis technique. For recursion, you always need to ask two questions: How do I get to the next step? How do I know when I'm done?

The second question is easy: you've already figured out that the base case is `aabbb` (that is, `i=2, j=3`). No shorter word can be part of the grammar.

Now, suppose we have a longer word, which means that `i` must be greater than 2. How do we get to the next step? In other words, how do we find a shorter valid word? We can remove an `a` (decrement `i`), but then we also need to fix `j`. From the inequalities, it's clear that `j` can be decremented by either two or three (it's possible that both would work, but one of the two must work).

That will result in an ambiguous grammar, but the question doesn't say that the grammar needs to be unambiguous. However, it's easy to come up with an unambiguous grammar, based on the strategy of always resolving the decision (two or three) in the same direction, if both answers are possible.